# If I copy a pem file between multiple computers will I still be able to ssh to amazon e2 instance?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vps

While you creating an instances of Amazon EC2.  A step is to generate a pem file.  This file allows the sshing into the remote EC2 instance from local.

**Question:**If I copy that pem file to another computer will it work the same?  or is this bound to the hardware also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work. If you would like to access your Amazon EC2 instance from any other machine. You can copy the pem file to that machine and you can ssh to Amazon EC2 instance.